# Next Sunday In Oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to get the next Sunday of the provided date(bind variable in my query). So I wrote as below.

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY(NVL(TO_DATE(:1,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'31-DEC-9999'),'SUN') FROM DUAL
```

This is working for all dates except if the day is Sunday itself. If the day is Sunday itself, it should not give next Sunday, rather it should return same day.

Answer (score 2):

Before discussing the answer I would like to address two dependencies of your approach.

**First** - you depend on the default DATE format

```
 NVL(TO_DATE(:1,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'31-DEC-9999')
```

The first parameter of the NVL is date, the second is String to be converted to DATE

**Second** using 'SUN' in the query depends on the NLS settings. If the client has different `NLS_LANGUAGE` setting the query will fail. Try with

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE= 'GERMAN';
```

This formula return the **next Sunday in a NLS independent** way:

```
 my_date + 6 - (trunc(my_date) - trunc(my_date,'IW'))
```

Explanation

```
trunc(my_date) - trunc(my_date,'IW')
```

returns a number between 0 and 6. Zero for Monday till six for Sunday.

```
 6 - (trunc(my_date) - trunc(my_date,'IW'))
```

returns a number between 6 and 0. Six for Monday till zero for Sunday. That means this is the number of day until the next Sunday. Simple adding it to your date parameter it will return the next Sunday. (For Sunday you add zero i.e. as expected you get the same day).

**Test**

```
with my_dates as (
select  TO_DATE('28-10-2017','DD-MM-YYYY') + rownum -1 my_date  from DUAL connect by level <= 10 )

select my_date, trunc(my_date) - trunc(my_date,'IW')  day_of_week,
    6 - (trunc(my_date) - trunc(my_date,'IW')) days_to_next_sunday,
    -- next sunday formula
    my_date + 6 - (trunc(my_date) - trunc(my_date,'IW'))   next_sunday       
from my_dates;


MY_DATE   DAY_OF_WEEK DAYS_TO_NEXT_SUNDAY NEXT_SUNDAY
--------- ----------- ------------------- -----------
28-OCT-17           5                   1 29-OCT-17   
29-OCT-17           6                   0 29-OCT-17   
30-OCT-17           0                   6 05-NOV-17   
31-OCT-17           1                   5 05-NOV-17   
01-NOV-17           2                   4 05-NOV-17   
02-NOV-17           3                   3 05-NOV-17   
03-NOV-17           4                   2 05-NOV-17   
04-NOV-17           5                   1 05-NOV-17   
05-NOV-17           6                   0 05-NOV-17   
06-NOV-17           0                   6 12-NOV-17
```

So your query would be as follows

```
SELECT  
   my_date + 6 - (trunc(my_date) - trunc(my_date,'IW'))   next_sunday 
FROM   (SELECT TO_DATE(NVL(:1, '31-DEC-9999'), 'DD-MON-YYYY') my_date
        FROM   dual);
```

To use the expression in the `WHERE` clause simple use a subquery factoring with one row containing you parameter date and cross join it to your table:

```
with my_date as (SELECT TO_DATE(NVL(:1, '31-DEC-9999'), 'DD-MON-YYYY') my_date FROM   dual)
select * from my_tab d cross join my_date 
where D.CAL_DATE <= my_date + 6 - (trunc(my_date) - trunc(my_date,'IW'));
```

Comment: I am using it in a where condition. A part of code :                                               
Where TO_DATE(D.CAL_DATE) <= NEXT_DAY(NVL(TO_DATE(:1,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'31-DEC-9999'),'SUN')                                                                            
So I will have to write things that way.. Can you please help?

Comment: I added the usage in the WHERE clause, HTH.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `CASE` statement to compare.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN TRIM(TO_CHAR(dt, 'DAY')) = 'SUNDAY' THEN dt
         ELSE NEXT_DAY(dt, 'SUN')
       END sunday
FROM   (SELECT NVL(TO_DATE(:1, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), '31-DEC-9999') dt
        FROM   dual);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just subtract 1 day from your date and then use `NEXT_DAY`:

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY(
         NVL(
           TO_DATE( :1, 'DD-MON-YYYY' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY,
           DATE '9999-12-31'            -- Use a date literal
         ),
         'SUN'
       )
FROM   DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that I used.  It could be modified to take a starting date parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION nextweekday (
  dayofweek number -- 0 is sunday, 6 is saturday
)
-- this function will return the date of the next requested weekday. If the current date is the requested weekday, it will return the current date.
-- If you want the weekday after the next weekday then use values greater than 6 (ie. add 7 for each week further into the future).
-- If you want the previous weekday then subtract 14 from your value and then 7 for each preceding week before that
RETURN DATE
IS
    sundayNumber NUMBER; -- for what the DB says is the number for a Sunday - this will depend on NLS settings for this DB
    dow NUMBER; -- the dayofweek parameter converted to the number of the week the DB wants - this will depend on NLS settings for this DB
    todayNumber NUMBER; -- the day of the week of the current date
    daysToAdd NUMBER; -- number of days to add to the current date to get to the next required week day
BEGIN
    -- get the day number of a known Sunday and the current date
    SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2023/09/17', 'YYYY/MM/DD'), 'D')), TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D')) INTO sundayNumber, todayNumber
    FROM dual;

 

    -- convert the passed parameter to the DB's equivilent
    dow := dayofweek + sundayNumber;
    IF dow > 7 THEN
        dow := dow - 7;
    END IF;

 

    -- calculate the number of days to add to current date
    daysToAdd := dow - todayNumber;
    IF daysToAdd < 0 THEN
        daysToAdd := daysToAdd + 7;
    END IF;

 

    -- return the date of the requested week day
    RETURN sysdate + daysToAdd;
END;
```